# Curl request in bash with authorization how to escape ''

Tags: linux, bash, shell, curl

I writing a bash script to do a curl with custom headers. The request looks like

```
curl --location --request GET 'http://100.200.159.79:80/n_clone/' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer 5e0333f03d311b646f84424a047abef08433d9ed' \
--header 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------905029954124550761104092'
```

I want to add a variable after Bearer like

```
access_token= "5e0af6333f03b646f84424a047abef08433d9ed77411b4f4"
auth_head= "'Authorization: Bearer'$access_to"

get_data=$(curl --location --request GET "http://100.200.159.79:80/n_clone/" \
-H "Authorization: Bearer $access_token" \
-H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------651618584466976849992097")
```

I have also tried

```
get_data=$(curl --location --request GET 'http://100.200.159.79:80/n_clone/' \
-H 'Authorization: Bearer '$access_token \
-H 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------651618584466976849992097')
```

How can I insert a variable between `''` (single quotes) such that the curl request works fine? At this time it throws an error of Authorization field missing.

Comment: You shouldn't have *any* literal quotes in the header at all. Don't try to inject them. The only quotes that should be here are *syntactic* ones, read and then removed by the shell itself as it figures out how your string is supposed to be broken down into a list of individual arguments.

Comment: Also, spaces around the `=` in an assignment are disallowed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use double quotes for the whole string; there's no need for single quotes anywhere in the authorization header's definition at all.

```
access_token="5e0af6333f03b646f84424a047abef08433d9ed77411b4f4"
get_data=$(curl --location --request GET 'http://100.200.159.79:80/n_clone/' \
-H "Authorization: Bearer $access_token" \
-H 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------651618584466976849992097')
```

The only quotes we want here are *syntactic* ones, used by the shell. When you put quotes inside other quotes, they become *literal data*, passed to `curl`. If the remote server doesn't expect literal quote characters in its headers, we don't ever want to pass literal quotes to curl.

---

By the way, it would be equally valid to use:

```
-H 'Authorization: Bearer '"$access_token" \
```

...wherein we have the string `Authorization: Bearer` in a single-quoted context and then expand `$access_token` in a double-quoted context; the reason I didn't suggest that above is that `Authorization: Bearer` expands the same way in single and double quotes, so why use two different contexts when you could have only one?

Comment: BTW, this has been answered community-wiki as I believe the question is a duplicate, but haven't found the preexisting instance to flag it yet; don't want to be getting reputation points for knowingly answering a dupe.

Comment: thanks got the hang of it. Marking the question as duplicate.